# Storage access framework in android kitkat

Tags: android

My app needs to write to external secondary storage. Now with kitkat I cannot write to external storage apart from app specific files. There is new framework in kitkat called Storage Access Framework. Can I write to secondary external storage using this framework not in app specfic directory but other directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My app needs to write to external secondary storage

It is unclear what you mean by "external secondary storage".

> Now with kitkat I cannot write to external storage apart from app specific files

Your app can request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, in which case you can write to arbitrary locations on the device's designated external storage, such as `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. This has not changed in years.

> Can I write to secondary external storage using this framework not in app specfic directory but other directory

Not really. Storage Access Framework does not give *you* control over where things are read from; it gives the *user* control. It is designed for cloud-based storage providers, like Google Drive, DropBox, etc.

Comment: thanks for reply, by external secondary storage I mean external mounted sd card. I think writing to mounted sd card require permission that require app to be signed with platform key and cannot be used by third party. So by using Storage Access Framework I cannot write to external storage. Can you give me any link for reference where it is mentioned I cannot write to external storage using this framework in kitkat and all data is written to device storage.

Comment: @anujprashar: "I think writing to mounted sd card require permission that require app to be signed with platform key and cannot be used by third party" -- no, it's more that the Android SDK does not expose APIs to work with arbitrary locations on such cards. Android 4.4 did add some methods on `Environment` to help with this, but they are only equivalents of `getExternalFilesDir()`, not access to arbitrary locations.

Comment: @anujprashar: "Can you give me any link for reference where it is mentioned I cannot write to external storage using this framework in kitkat and all data is written to device storage" -- that is not what my answer contains. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare am using setDestinationInExternalFilesDir on DownloadManager.Request, but on kitkat it is asking me to have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. But according to the docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles), I don't need it ???

Comment: @sirackh: The docs say that you do not need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` if *you* are writing to `getExternalFilesDir()` on Android 4.4+. In this case, you are not writing to `getExternalFilesDir()` -- you are asking *another app* (the Download app) to write to external storage. That app requires you to hold `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Answer (score 7):

Android's definition of external storage is here:
http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/index.html

Details about writing to secondary external storage:

> The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission must only grant write access to
>   the primary external storage on a device. Apps must not be allowed to
>   write to secondary external storage devices, except in their
>   package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions.
>   Restricting writes in this way ensures the system can clean up files
>   when applications are uninstalled.

Interesting point for KitKat is that writing to secondary external storage (such as SD memory card) is prohibited, except of app's specific directory, which is deleted during app uninstall.

On KitKat, apps can't write to arbitrary location on real SD card (= secondary external storage), even if having WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Android has another WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE permission, which allows write to these locations, however this permission is not given to 3rd party app, only some built-in apps hold it, such as Camera app or internal file manager.

All this is kind of mess, apps can write anything to device's internal mass memory and leave any garbage there even after uninstalling, however apps can't write anything to real external SD card. Many users perceive this as Android's bug or mistake introduced in KitKat, and waiting for better solution to protect storage in next Android version (I know it as I develop a file manager app used by million users).

Comment: Goog explanation and I fully agree with your last sentense. Also my app-users bought an external sdcard to store the amount of my app. Now they can't use it. This is a wrong concept from google and I don't see any security or quality enhancement on this new concept.

Answer (score 0):

Android api level 19 and 20 completely forbids modifying external storage(SdCard). You can however read external storage such as Open File or listing Directory files or getting file attributes.

From api level 21 and up, the Storage Access Framework updated to allow modification of SdCard if user explicitly allowed it. You will receive a document tree Uri and must use the DocumentsContract api to modify the SdCard such as create file/folder, rename, open outputstream.

Working with DocumentsContract is very clunky and it is highly undocumented. Thus you will do alot of trial and error, and research. DocumentFile was introduced in api level 26, and everybody seems to be using it. However api level 26 is Android 8 and I only have Android 7.0. Plus Android reference warned that DocumentFile has too much overhead and recommends to use DoumentsContract. Aso, I think I read that DocumentFile is not supported in Android 10 and up.