# App crashing after taking picture and while delivering the result to onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I am trying to take a picture by calling camera intent and show it in a image view. My code works on almost all devices except on some MI Devices with kitkat version. Here is my code

```
     private void initializeCameraIntent() {
            Permiso.getInstance().requestPermissions(new Permiso.IOnPermissionResult() {
           /* if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){*/
                @Override
                public void onPermissionResult(Permiso.ResultSet resultSet) {
                    if (resultSet.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        File photoFile = null;
                        try {
                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onTileSelected: ", ex);
                        }
                        if (photoFile != null) {
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                            imageUri = uri.toString();
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MessagesFragment.this.getActivity(),
                                getString(R.string.msg_permission_required), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onRationaleRequested(Permiso.IOnRationaleProvided callback, String... permissions) {
                    Permiso.getInstance().showRationaleInDialog(null,
                            getString(R.string.msg_permission_required),
                            null, callback);
                }
            }, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
 protected File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp;
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }

 @Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                    if (!imageUri.isEmpty()) {
                        showSendImageFragment(imageUri);
                        imageUri = "";
                    }
                    break;
}
```

And below is the exception thrown in some devices

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.view.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please Someone help me fixing this. It works on every Other device.

Comment: Is your external storage in those mi kitkat devices an SD-card? If yes, there is trouble writing to the SD card in KitKat. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22603042/3635454

Answer (score 0):

Its a MI devices Security issue.You wont be able to get the direct path of your selected file They will just provide only the content provider Url
I suggested you use this [Coomar Picker Library](https://github.com/coomar2841/android-multipicker-library).I also got stuck on the same issue for so many days.This is the only solution i have found it.This will save your time

And Here is the wiki for it [WIKI](https://github.com/coomar2841/android-multipicker-library/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

I think your imageUri is becoming null when your are calling startActivityForResult(intent) method you can replicate the issue on other devices by going to developer options enabling do not keep activities option to overcome this issue. Override `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (imageUri != null){
        outState.putString("cameraImageUri", imageUri.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("cameraImageUri")){
        imageUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("imageUri"));
    }
}
```